# The term "proto" in "proto-language"

Tags: terminology, historical-linguistics, writing-systems

I noticed that both Proto-Sinaitic and Proto-Indo-European have the title of "proto", although the Proto-Sinaitic has actual scripts which were found and studied, i.e. it is a fact that it existed, while PIE is completely reconstructed. If so what does "proto" mean? Should Proto-Sinaitic not be considered proto anymore, but rather "ancient", or should it have it's own word?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

By convention, the prefix *proto-* is only assigned to reconstructed languages predating the extant records of related languages. In rare cases it happens that older records show up and a proto-language gets to the status of a real language (the only example that comes to my mind is the case of Old Norse ⁒ Proto-Germanic).

However, Proto-Sinaitic is not a language but a writing system. The terminology of paleographers differs from the terminology of linguists in this respect, it allows the prefix *proto* for an attested writing system that is the predecessor of another writing system.

Comment: I think paleographers can also use it for "reconstructions",  I don't think everything that falls under "Proto-Cuneiform" is authentic for instance; I have run into reconstructions of Proto-Cuneiform based on Cuneiform descendants.